# Loop through multiple files in folder and copy/paste to master file

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy from multiple files in a specific folder and paste into a Master file. All files have a sheet called "Analysis", variable rows, but constant columns. I need to copy from all files the sheet "Analysis" A4:AB and paste in workbook called "Evaluations" in Sheet called "Evaluations" G2:AH, one below the other. I have the below code, which worked but doesn't anymore and I don't know why. Can you please help?

```
Sub CopyRange()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim wkbDest As Workbook
    Dim wkbSource As Workbook
    Set wkbDest = ThisWorkbook
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Const strPath As String = "V:\Trade Marketing\Trade Finance\2021\Projects\Evaluation\Analysis\"
    ChDir strPath
    strExtension = Dir("*.xls*")
    Do While strExtension <> ""
        Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strExtension)
        With wkbSource
                    lastRow = .Sheets("Analysis").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
            .Sheets("Analysis").Range("A4:AB" & lastRow).Copy wkbDest.Sheets("Evaluations").Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            .Close SaveChanges:=False
        End With
        strExtension = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you receive any error message? If so, which line?

Comment: You have 2 ways of defining the last row, i'd recommend using the way you use in the paste to define the copy range also.

Comment: Hi Raymond, thank you for reaching out. I did not receive any error message. I try to run it and it does nothing.

Comment: Hi Nathan, thank you for your message. I still do not get any respond when running the code.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code to see what's happening?  Are there files?  Are they being opened?

Comment: @MariaPapadopoulou Is the folder path in `strPath` valid?

Comment: I have 58 files in the folder, all in xlsx file format. Now, for no reason at all, it worked, I did not change anything. Any thoughts as to why this could be happening?

Comment: @MariaPapadopoulou Is V drive a mapped/network drive?

Comment: @Raymond yes V is a network drive.

Comment: @MariaPapadopoulou I'm not confident that this is the reason but it happened to me before that ChDir to a network drive doesn't work properly until I have browse it in File Explorer so if possible, try providing the UNC path to ChDir. (or, if it happens again, browse to the folder in File Explorer then try again)

Comment: @RaymondWu thank you very much for your assistance! I will try what you propose next time.

Comment: Why would you do `ChDir strPath`? Who knows what is 'its result'. Just do `strExtension = Dir(strPath & "*.xls*")`. Also, the result is a file name, so the variable name is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

### Backup Data Columns

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub AnalysisBackup()
    
    Const swbPath As String _
        = "V:\Trade Marketing\Trade Finance\2021\Projects\Evaluation\Analysis\"
    Const swbPattern As String = "*.xls*"
    
    Const sName As String = "Analysis"
    Const sCols As String = "A:AB"
    Const sFirstRow As Long = 4
    
    Const dName As String = "Evaluations"
    Const dFirst As String = "G2"
    
    Dim swbName As String: swbName = Dir(swbPath & swbPattern)
    If swbName = "" Then Exit Sub ' no file found
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = dws.Columns(sCols).Columns.Count
    Dim dirrg As Range: Set dirrg = dws.Range(dFirst).Resize(, cCount)
    Dim drrg As Range ' Destination First Row Range
    Dim dlCell As Range ' Destination Last Cell
    Set dlCell = dirrg.Resize(dws.Rows.Count - dirrg.Row + 1) _
        .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    If dlCell Is Nothing Then
        Set drrg = dirrg
    Else
        Set drrg = dirrg.Offset(dlCell.Row - dirrg.Row + 1)
    End If
            
    Dim swb As Workbook ' Source Workbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet ' Source Worksheet
    Dim srg As Range ' Source Range
    Dim slCell As Range ' Source Last Cell
    Dim srCount As Long ' Source Range Rows Count
    
    Dim drg As Range ' Destination Range
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Do While swbName <> ""
        Set swb = Workbooks.Open(swbPath & swbName)
        Set sws = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set sws = swb.Worksheets(sName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not sws Is Nothing Then
            Set slCell = Nothing
            With sws.Rows(sFirstRow).Columns(sCols)
                Set slCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
                    .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
                If Not slCell Is Nothing Then
                    srCount = slCell.Row - .Row + 1
                    Set srg = .Resize(srCount)
                    Set drg = drrg.Resize(srCount)
                    drg.Value = srg.Value
                    Set drrg = drrg.Offset(srCount)
                'Else ' empty source range
                End If
            End With
        'Else ' source worksheet does not exist
        End If
        swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        swbName = Dir
    Loop
    
    'dwb.Save
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Analysis backup created.", vbInformation, "Analysis Backup"
    
End Sub
```